# Passing a xml from php to javascript as an object

Tags: javascript, php, xml, json, object

I have a xml that describes the menu of a website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
        <item titulo="Início" tipo="conteudo" codigo="inicio" classe="btnMenu01" />
        <item titulo="O Sintran" tipo="submenu" codigo="osintran" classe="btnMenu01">
            <subitem titulo="Apresentação" tipo="pagina" codigo="apresentacao" classe="btnMenu02" />
            <subitem titulo="Editorial" tipo="lista" param="artigos,assunto,editorial" codigo="editorial" classe="btnMenu02" />
            <subitem titulo="Estatuto" tipo="arquivos" param="descricao,estatuto" codigo="estatuto" classe="btnMenu02" />
        </item>
        <item titulo="Notícias" tipo="conteudo" codigo="noticias" classe="btnMenu01" />
        etc...
    </menu>
```

There will be only two level, so it's simple. I'm passing to JavaScript by this line:

```
var SubMenus = <?php echo(json_encode($SubMenus)) ?>;
```

Than I can enumerate the values I need by:

```
for(i in SubMenus){
    console.log("Submenu "+i+"...");
    Atts = SubMenus[i]["@attributes"];
    for(j in Atts){
        console.log(" - "+j+": "+Atts[j]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that @attributes means nothing to a JavaScript Object type, I discovered this property by myself. So I'm not sure if I'm using the right technic for the task, I'm may using a method that will crash when things got complicated...

How do you do this task? Or you think is ok like this?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
Atts = SubMenus[i].attributes;
// did not work for user
```

**UPDATE**: Check out this [post on converting xml to an object with javascript](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json), and it'll also show how you can access/print it out